# Create XML digital signature using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, digital-signature

I need to create [XML digital signature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) on client.

I have plugin through which I can get:

- Digest value using specified digest method
- Signature value using certificate which client selected
- X509Data

But I cannot make canonicalization and transformation using specified methods.

Canonicalization: [xml-exc-c14n](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/).

Transformation: [enveloped-signature](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd#enveloped-signature).

Is there any JavaScript libraries which can make canonicalization and transformation of XML document?

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: It would be a better idea to move all business logic to Java applet. You would be able to sign the data easily then.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp yes, that would be great, but in that case I would not be able to use certificates. I can get certificates and required digest/signature methods only through plugin.

Comment: who said you can't? In our SecureBlackbox product we do exactly this -- client-side Java applet uses certificates from client's certificate storages (windows and PKCS#11) to sign data.

Comment: You may use Browser Extension to achieve this for modern browsers. Signer Digital Chrome Extension is one such available free from my Company.